# Is it possible to tell Safari to repeat a table header on printed pages?

Tags: html, safari, html-table

Is it possible to repeat table headers in Safari on every printed page?

This code works in Firefox but not in Safari:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Header1</td>
      <td>Header2</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <!-- lots of rows -->
</table>
```

**Edit:**

the following doesn't fix it, therefore it can't be the same bug that IE has:

```
thead { display:table-header-group; }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer my own question:

After googling and getting no correct answer I think that there exists simply no method to accomplish it. Maybe later versions of Safari will include it.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider reprinting the `thead` periodically as you go down the table. If the table is rather long, this might prove beneficial even when viewed on screen, as the header will most likely scroll off the screen pretty quickly. If you don't want to show it on screen, though, you could add a class to the reprinted headers, hide them on screen, and display them only in the print stylesheet.

Comment: That would require you to know where the break of the table occurs, which is actually impossible. (Because the break might move if you insert a new row.)

Comment: Well, if your rows are all the same height (which, they may not be), then you can pretty accurately predict where the break will occur with a few quick tests.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider creating a CSS sheet for the printed version of your page. If you opt for that route, use the "position:fixed;". Elements positioned as 'fixed' are printed on every printed page.

The tricky part is that any positioned element (i.e. position property is not 'static') is taken out of the document flow. This makes alignment, of other (regular flowing) elements with the fixed elements tough.

Based on the information in your question, I would wrap the *entire* table in a fixed element (or create a class such as .printedTable with the position property set to fixed).  This way, the table structure would repeat on each printed page.

Good luck. 
A.

Comment: Only the header of the table should be repeated, not the whole table as it is larger than a single page.

Comment: I would create just a 'fixed' header element so it repeats on every page and set the page top margin to a large enough value to prevent the page / table content from being rendered under the fixed heading. The pages can then have the table content printed with the header repeated on every prntd page